# Specflow don't running with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, mstest, specflow

When I run my Specflow Scenario nothing happens (still pending)... I am working with Visual Studio 2012 and Resharper. All steps are bound...

[image]

Here is my configuration for my Spec project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

I tried many options for Test Runner Tool (Tools > Options > SpecFlow) and nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry, we will need more information to go on. Can you extract the a small example that isn't working and provide both the feature file and the bindings for that?

Comment: I have an error but my problem is I don't have any feedback with Unit Test Sessions View (I tried with Test Explorer View and that's work better)

Comment: `Pending` means that the bindings haven't been found, so unless you can demonstrate what is wrong that part of your code, then you are not providing enough information for anyone to help.